# eclipse , git integration

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm used to working with git repository.

Eclipse is peculiar in a sense it creates a copy (workspace) and modifies files there.

I'd like to modify codes where `.git` resides so that I can commit easily.

I don't need eclipse's git gui.
I just want to be able to do modify files and do git operations in the cloned directory (not the workspace directory)

Is this possible?

Comment: EGit (Eclispe Git integration) does not copy cloned repo. By default it imports the projects directly from the clone, so you can use command line Git to work with your repo. Perhaps you have cloned twice? First the remote repo and then the fresh local one in Eclipse? Use "Add an existing local repo..." if you have already cloned a repository from command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I've ever just used an Eclipse-made copy in my workspace. I always put the git repo inside my workspace.

Just move the root folder of your git repository into your Eclipse workspace folder, then import it via either the Eclipse 'Import' or 'New Project' wizards. The settings & choices for the import depend on the type of project you're working on.